# Issue with object as parameter in REST API Service

Tags: xml, wcf, rest

EDIT:
Apparently what I have is working. I had been testing using the xml generated from the serialized object, which wasn't working.  I was messing with it more just now and decided to try using the dynamic XML that I am creating (same as posted here), and it worked.  I think maybe it was because when i was trying it that way before I wasn't using the same namespaces...
However, how come using the xml from the serialized object doesn't work?  I noticed it uses different namespace in the xml when it is created from the object.  Why is that?

**Original post:**
I am having an issue with passing a custom object to a REST API I'm creating.  Right now I am just trying to test it by posting an object of type Lead to a WebInvoke method.
My service is written with WCF.  The Lead object is in a separate class library project that will by my business logic layer.

I'm posting using a regular ASP .net page.  You'll see in that section of code below that I tried building the xml in two ways, manually, and also by Serializing the object as xml and using that as the POST data.  Neither work, and I'm getting this error:
The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.

I know the service is configured correctly, as I'm able to call and get a response from the other WebInvoke method I have written, which is a GET method.

Here is the releveant code:
Service interface code:

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://www.mytestnamespace.com/test")]
public interface IRESTService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
        UriTemplate = "leads",
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml)]
    string AddLead(Lead lead);

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
        UriTemplate = "lead/{id}",
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml)]
    string LeadData(string id);
}
```

Service code:

```
public class RESTService : IRESTService
{
    public string AddLead(Lead lead)
    {
        return "AddLead Hit";
    }

    public string LeadData(string id)
    {
        return "LeadData was hit, id=" + id;
    }
}
```

Lead object Code:

```
[DataContract(Name="Lead",
    Namespace = "http://www.mytestnamespace.com/test")]
public class Lead
{
    [DataMember(Name="FirstName")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "LastName")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "Phone")]
    public string Phone { get; set; }
}
```

And finally the code i'm using on the aspx page to post the data:

```
try
    {
        Lead l = new Lead();
        l.FirstName = "John";
        l.LastName = "Doe";
        l.Email = "John.Doe@gmail.com";
        l.Phone = "5555551234";

        XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Lead));
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        ser.Serialize(sw, l);

        string s = sw.ToString();




        /*XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        XmlDeclaration dec = doc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", null);

        XmlElement root = doc.CreateElement("Lead");
        root.SetAttribute("xmlns", "http://www.mytestnamespace.com/test");
        //root.SetAttribute("xmlns:xsd", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
        doc.InsertBefore(dec, doc.DocumentElement);
        doc.AppendChild(root);

        XmlElement firstName = doc.CreateElement("FirstName");
        XmlElement lastName = doc.CreateElement("LastName");
        XmlElement email = doc.CreateElement("Email");
        XmlElement phone = doc.CreateElement("Phone");

        firstName.AppendChild(doc.CreateTextNode("John"));
        lastName.AppendChild(doc.CreateTextNode("Doe"));
        email.AppendChild(doc.CreateTextNode("John.Doe@gmail.com"));
        phone.AppendChild(doc.CreateTextNode("8885551234"));

        root.AppendChild(firstName);
        root.AppendChild(lastName);
        root.AppendChild(email);
        root.AppendChild(phone);*/

        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri("http://localhost:54966/RESTService.svc/leads"));
        req.Method = "POST";
        req.ContentType = "application/xml";
        //byte[] formData = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(doc.InnerXml);
        byte[] formData = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s);
        req.ContentLength = formData.Length;

        using (Stream post = req.GetRequestStream())
        {
            post.Write(formData, 0, formData.Length);
        }

        string result = null;
        using (HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse())
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream());
            result = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
        throw exc;
    }
```

Comment: You are using a XmlSerializer to serialize your Lead object and guess your service uses DataContractSerializer to deserialze it and hence you get a 400 Bad request error. Try using DataContractSerializer on the object.

Answer (score 1):

While you can serialize IXmlSerializable, [Serializable], POCO, etc. types with DataContractSerializer as if they would have been serialized with their native serializers, the reverse is not true. You can't serialize / deserialize [DataContract] types with other serializers and still get the result you actually intend to get. In this case, XmlSerializer completely ignores the [DataContract] attributes altogether, but it doesn't throw an exception. This is because it assumes that it's like another POCO (plain old C# object) type with public fields and properties, and tries to serialize it using that model.

For more information about this, see the blog posts at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sowmy/archive/2006/02/22/536747.aspx and http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sowmy/archive/2006/05/14/why-prevent-datacontract-ixmlserializable.aspx

So, the solution here is one of two things:
- Remove DataContract etc. from your DataContract type, and start using [Serializable], IXmlSerializable, ISerializable, POCO, or some other serializaton mechanism that you can use with XmlFormatter or XmlSerializer

- Remove XmlSerializer usage and use DataContractSerializer instead.